# How to install Snapcraft on 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I am trying to follow [Getting set up](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/get-started/) instructions for installing Snapcraft on Ubuntu 14.04 (the document is ambiguous about 14.04 and 16.04, but [1.x](https://github.com/ubuntu-core/snapcraft/blob/1.x/docs/get-started.md) installation procedure seems to be exactly the same).

I follow the steps, get no error, however I cannot get `snapcraft` installed.

- Check the version:

  ```
  $ lsb_release -a
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
  Release:    14.04
  Codename:   trusty
  ```
- Add the repository:

  ```
  $ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:snappy-dev/tools
  ...
  OK
  ```
- Run update:

  ```
  $ sudo apt update
  ... (altogether 57 lines, no error) ...
  Reading package lists... Done
  ```
- Install `snappy-tools`

  ```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree
  Reading state information... Done
  The following extra packages will be installed:
    android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot apparmor-easyprof binfmt-support click-reviewers-tools click-ubuntu-policy
    debsig-verify kpartx libxmltok1 python3-apparmor python3-bs4 python3-html5lib python3-libapparmor python3-lxml python3-magic
  Preparing to unpack .../snappy-tools_10_amd64.deb ...
  Unpacking snappy-tools (10) ...
  Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
  Processing triggers for systemd (225-1ubuntu9) ...
  Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
  Setting up binfmt-support (2.1.5-1) ...
  Setting up python3-lxml (3.4.4-1) ...
  Setting up python3-magic (1:5.22+15-2ubuntu1) ...
  Setting up python3-simplejson (3.7.3-1ubuntu1) ...
  Setting up python3-xdg (0.25-4) ...
  Setting up click-reviewers-tools (0.34) ...
  Setting up libxmltok1 (1.2-3build3) ...
  Setting up debsig-verify (0.13) ...
  Setting up python3-bs4 (4.3.2-2ubuntu4) ...
  Setting up python3-html5lib (0.999-3build1) ...
  Setting up qemu-user-static (1:2.3+dfsg-5ubuntu9.2) ...
  Setting up seccomp (2.2.3-2ubuntu1) ...
  Setting up snappy-remote (0.4-0ubuntu1build1) ...
  # -*- mode: ruby -*-
  Setting up android-tools-adb (4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu42) ...
  Setting up android-tools-fastboot (4.2.2+git20130218-3ubuntu42) ...
  Setting up click-ubuntu-policy (0.1) ...
  Setting up kpartx (0.5.0-7ubuntu7.1) ...
  Setting up ubuntu-snappy-cli (1.5ubuntu1) ...
  Warning: The home dir /nonexistent you specified can't be accessed: No such file or directory
  Adding system user `snappypkg' (UID 115) ...
  Adding new group `snappypkg' (GID 121) ...
  Adding new user `snappypkg' (UID 115) with group `snappypkg' ...
  Not creating home directory `/nonexistent'.
  Setting up ubuntu-device-flash (0.31-0ubuntu1) ...
  Setting up ubuntu-core-security-seccomp (15.10.17) ...
  Setting up python3-libapparmor (2.10-0ubuntu6) ...
  ```
- Verify the installation:

  ```
  $ which snappy
  /usr/bin/snappy
  $ which snappy-remote
  /usr/bin/snappy-remote
  $ which snapcraft
  $ snapcraft
  snapcraft: command not found
  $ find / -name snapcraft 2> /dev/null
  $
  ```

Am I missing something here?

Also `snappy` and `snappy-remote` although being installed give an error:

```
$ snappy try
Unknown command `try'. Please specify one command of: booted, build, config, firstboot, hw-assign, hw-info, hw-unassign, info, install, internal-run-hooks, internal-unpack, list, login, purge, remove, rollback, search, set, update or versions
$ snappy-remote
the required flag `--url' was not specified
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36643/discussion-between-mohit-rajan-and-techraf).

Comment: As Mohit told in the chat, you didn't paste the whole output of snappy-tools install so that we can help you.

Please try:
```apt-cache policy snapcraft;
apt install snapcraft```

and paste both outputs here.

Comment: @didrocks Yes, you can help me without the full output of snappy-tools install (which I include anyway). Actually you even provided an answer. The manual I referenced does not mention `snapcraft` as being separate package and clearly says I "will get (it) after installation" of snappy-tools. Of course `apt install snapcraft` did install it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your feedback! I have written a proper answer until I fix it in the distro, do you mind accepting it so that people can get to it easily? Thanks :)

Comment: Currently, the page http://snapcraft.io/docs/build-snaps/ doesn't provide instructions for 14.04 any more. Seems that it is too difficult to support 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that we have a bug in our packaging metadata for 14.04. This is going to be fixed, but if you encounter that case, just ensure that snapcraft is installed:

```
sudo apt install snapcraft
```

As long as `snappy try` and `snappy-remote` gives some output, it means they are installed. We will switch them with `--help` in future release as the error they trigger without any argument can be puzzling.

Comment: More important than `--help` for snappy-tools would be `-v` / `--version`.

Comment: Good idea, wil do this.

Answer (score 2):

Snapcraft can be also installed with `snap` itself:

```
sudo snap install snapcraft
```

I don't know if it is a preffered way over `apt` or not though.

Comment: This is indeed now the preferred way to install snapcraft.